# HTML - Image is not showing

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I'm trying to show an image on my Asp.NET MVC 2 project but it is not working. I already tried a lot of things. I know that the path of the file is valid, because when I type `"src="` on Visual Studio 2010, it gives me the option to pick the URL and shows me all classes from my project.

My image tag looks like:

```
<img class="foo" src="Images/logo.jpg"/>
```

Inside of my view's folder, I have another folder called "Images" where I placed the "logo.jpg" file.

My css for the image is actually just:

```
.foo
{
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: When you run the web page in browser, the image file's path should match with that of the web page. I.e. if web page path is `/Default.aspx` then your `Images/logo.jpg` should be present in the same folder where `Default.aspx` file is placed in the server.

Comment: @seganfredo: have you checked your browser console? or try adding full path of the image i.e. from root to your image ex: `/Views/Images/logo.jpg`

Comment: @Ravinder my Images folder is present in the same folder than my Default.aspx file. The actual path is: Views/Home/Images/logo.jpg. My Default.aspx path's : Views/Home/Default.aspx

Comment: @seganfredo: Use an Absolute path for image src like `src="/Images/logo.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvF9V/1/) of you code which works fine

**Code:**

```
   <img class="foo" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQkcXs-qFPpoDX2Yh7A6IMRtoNvLRa-Fj_MKaIBal92xgo--7DDyQ"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo
{
   position: relative;
}
```

The problem is with the Source of the image in visual studio after src=" pickurl

[image]

choose the image Source form **PickURL** and before doing so add the image to your project

[image]

Locate the image file and then add it to the project then add the URL source of the image

Hope it helps

## **Updated**

```
<img class="foo" src="@Url.Content("~/View/Images/logo.jpg")/>
```

Double check the **image extension** too

Answer (score 1):

It seems more likely that ASP.NET is treating your `Images` directory as a protected resource, since it's within the `Views` directory. This bit in the `web.config` prevents directory browsing:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Move the `Images` directory to either the site root or the `Content` directory, and then (assuming you're using WebPages syntax) modify the `src` property of your images to one of these (depending on where you move it):

`<%: Url.Content("~/Images/YourImages.png") %>`

or

`<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Images/YourImages.png") %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<img class="foo" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Views/Home/Images/logo.jpg") %>" />`

Comment: The image didn't open. When i try to do that i recieve an "Application Server Error '/'"

Comment: Where is your image located in relation to the root directory?

Comment: It's placed on my Visual Studio's projects folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but I had the same problem of yours before but I used MVC 4.
try adding the ProjectName/FolderName to the path.

```
<img class="foo" src="<projectName>/Images/logo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: In MVC4+, you should just be using a `~` to begin a path in your views; the view engine is smart enough to know it has to map the virtual path.

Answer (score -1):

@seganfredo, @Ravinder: Yeah try and use an absolute path and work your way backwards. Like:

```
<img src="http://my-site.com/path/to/img/Images/logo.jpg"/>
```